# MySQL-python Delete Query is NOT deleting data, but no error is displayed

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm working on a terminal-password-manager with Python and SQL, everything works fine except for the delete function, I've managed to set it up in a way where no errors are displayed, however the delete query doesn't seem to be working because it doesn't actually delete the row from the table. So I can't really understand why this happening because no errors are thrown.

As you can see in this image:
[image: the problem]

Here is the code:

**delete entry function:**

```py
    def deleteEntry(sitename, siteurl, email, username):
        # check entry existence
        if checkEntryForDelete(sitename):
            printc("[yellow][-] There aren't any entries with those parameters...[/yellow]")
            return

        # remove from database  
        db = dbconfig()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        query = "DELETE FROM pmdatabase.entries WHERE sitename = '{sitename}' AND siteurl = '{siteurl}' AND email = '{email}' AND username = '{username}'"
        #val = (sitename,siteurl,email,username)
        cursor.execute(query)
        db.commit()

        printc("[red][-][/red] Entry Deleted ")
```

**main file:**

```py
    if args.option in ["delete","d"]:
        if args.name == None or args.url == None or args.login == None:
            if args.name == None:
                printc("[red][!] Site Name (-s) is required and was not specified[/red]")
            if args.url == None:
                printc("[red][!] Site URL (-u) is required and was not specified[/red]")
            if args.login == None:
                printc("[red][!] Site Login User or Name (-l) is required and was not specified[/red]")
            return
        if args.email == None:
            printc("[red][!] Site Email (-l) is required and was not specified[/red]")
        
        res = inputAndValidateMasterPassword()
        if res is not None:
            utils.delete.deleteEntry(args.name,args.url,args.email,args.login)
            #utils.delete.deleteEntry(args.name)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you try the query directly in MySQL?

Comment: @wkl it says: *You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option....*

Comment: Can you try this and see if it works in your Python code? I added a `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query: `"DELETE FROM pmdatabase.entries WHERE sitename = '{sitename}' AND siteurl = '{siteurl}' AND email = '{email}' AND username = '{username}' LIMIT 1"`

Comment: @wkl Thank you so much for your answer, the `LIMIT 1` was just what I needed, after that I only had to do a slight modification to the query, passing some values, for example `sitename=%s`. That seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `LIMIT 1` in my query (suggested by @wkl in the comments) made it so that the query worked in MySQL if I passed the values right into it, like:

`DELETE FROM pmdatabase.entries WHERE sitename = 'test' AND siteurl = 'test.com' AND email = 'test@email.com' AND username = 'testuser' limit 1`

but this wouldn't work with my Python code because I need the values to be taken from the user input, that's why I decided to use placeholders (%s) to then pass the values into them with a *tuple* with parameter values:

```py
# remove from database  
    db = dbconfig()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = "DELETE FROM pmdatabase.entries WHERE sitename = %s AND siteurl = %s AND email = %s AND username = %s LIMIT 1"
    tuple1 = (sitename,siteurl,email,username)
    cursor.execute(query, tuple1)
    db.commit()
```

And that seems to work.

[image: delete-works]

Comment: Glad I could help. A further explanation for this is that MySQL defaults to something called Safe Update Mode, which doesn't allow destructive queries like `DELETE` and `UPDATE` without specifying `LIMIT` or a `WHERE` cause with a key in it. An alternative  to `LIMIT` for you would be to [create an index on at least one of the columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html), which would allow you to run your query without needing `LIMIT 1`. It seems like your table doesn't have a primary key on it, which would be an easy index to have.